# Reprocessing Outlook Undelivered Mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook, exchange-server

I have an Exchange mailbox with a bunch of Outlook [ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem) Undelivered messages. I am attempting to reprocess the undelivered messages via an Outlook VBA script by invoking the "SendAgain" operation on the `ReportItem` messages. My issue is that the `ReportItem` does not have a send method, so I have no way of actually sending the reprocessed messages. I am using the following code to go through the messages:

```
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim journalAlertInbox As Folder

Dim objInspector As Inspector
Dim resendItem As ReportItem

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set journalAlertInbox = objNameSpace.Stores.Item("thestore").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each folderItem In journalAlertInbox.Items
    If TypeOf folderItem Is ReportItem Then
        folderItem.Display
        Set objInspector = folderItem.GetInspector
        objInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "SendAgain"
    
        Set resendItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Set objInspector = resendItem.GetInspector
        ''how do I send the item that is now displayed?
        ''resendItem.Close olSave
        folderItem.Close olDiscard
    End If
Next folderItem
```

I thought I might be able to save the displayed message as a draft, however If I uncomment the `resendItem.close olSave` line this results in a message in my Outlook Drafts folder of type `ReportItem`. I can open up the saved draft message it the Outlook GUI and click the send button, but I do not see a way to actually invoke the send operation programmatically. Examining the message in drafts shows it to be of type `ReportItem`, which does not have a `.Send` method.

How can I invoke the "Send" operation on the Report Item? I can clearly see the "Send" button, but there seems to be no programmatic way of actually clicking it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOM does not expose any functionality that allows to link a `ReportItem` object to the original `MailItem`, and, generally, there might not be any kind of link between the two. The best you can do is to retrieve `PR_ORIGINAL_SEARCH_KEY` MAPI property (or `PR_REPORT_TAG`, which includes both the search key and the store/Sent Items folder entry id) using `ReportItem.PropertyAccess.GetProperty` and try to find a matching message in the Sent Items folder. You can see these properties in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author).
Keep in mind that OOM does not allow to search on the binary (`PT_BINARY`) properties in `Items.Find/Restrict`.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am also its author), it exposes [RDOReportItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOReportItem.htm).`FindOriginalItem` method.

Once you have the original item, you can make a copy and try to send it again.

Comment: I am assuming you accidentally omitted "not" in relation to OOM and the link from a ReportItem back to a MailItem above. Is Redemption open source, where it's code base could reviewed? You can understand that our information security department would be wary of me using a 3rd party library against our email system without a review.

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that! Redemption is not open source. It is a commercial product first released in the early 2000s and is being used by tens of thousands of developers and millions of end users.

Comment: Thanks for the information on Redemption; I will definately consider and take a look at it. Do you have any thoughts on the approach suggested by Eugene Astafiev with respect to attempting to pluck out the `MailItem` from the `Conversation` object of the `ReportItem`?

Comment: I have never tried that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReportItem` doesn't represent the original item which is failed to be sent. Also it doesn't contain any relationship with the original mail item, so you will not find any property or method available in the Outlook object model. Your existing solution looks good.

You may also try using the [ReportItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem.getconversation) method which obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs. So, you may try getting the previous item from the conversation, it could be the original item which has been submitted.

Comment: I did some testing and `ReportItem.GetConversation` does not always return a `Conversation` object on the Undelivered message; does this seem correct? Why would this be the case?

Comment: Use the `IsConversationEnabled` property of the `Store` object to determine whether the store supports `Conversation` view. Conversations can be disabled through the Windows registry.